# Multiple concurrent WCF calls from single client to Service

Tags: wcf

I have a service that calls a service on another machine and the most number of concurrent connections I can get is 2.  I have tried changing the throttling on the WCF Service Behaviour but to no effect.  I have read that it is because of the HTTP limit of 2 concurrent connections from a client machine to a server.  How do I overcome this? The os on both machines is server 2003.

Config:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to overcome this from client code (from the service which calls other service). Use this code in the initialization of your service application to increase connections:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
```

Comment: It solved for me, after i tested outside the unit test.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding something like this in your app.config on your client app:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Will there be any impact on the application after adding this configuration?

Comment: @HimanshuJain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922699/disadvantage-of-increasing-servicepointmanager-defaultconnectionlimit