# C# simulate multiple clients calling randomly 10 web services

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, coyote

I have an `Azure App Service` that host a `WCF service`, this service consume a DB that is in `Azure SQL Database`.

Those `WCF Services` were installed in the past in a dedicated machine but because we are migrating to Azure we need to make sure that the selected `App Service Plan` and `Instance for Azure SQL Database` are enough for handling the normal load we have.

What I want to do is to create a `Winform` app, then reference the Azure WCF services and them implement call to just 10 methods (will choose the high load ones), and then create lets say **0 to 50** threads that can run simultaneously and execute inside randomly the 10 methods.

For example:

Thread **n** (Simulates Client #n)
Will run in sequence randomly the 10 methods

- `GetData1` method wait to finish then
- `GetData2` method wait to finish then
- `GetData3` method wait to finish then
- `GetData..10` method wait to finish.

So all threads has to run at the same time but the methods could be different so for **Thread 1** maybe the first method to run is `GetData4`, for **Thread 2** the first method to run could be `GetData10`, and so on.

And I have to log elapsed milliseconds that took each method on each thread to run. This way I would know that If I run 10 clients, I can see that maybe the response is all good, but If I run 25 maybe the response will have a bad delay and that will force me to scale up the App Service Plan and DB.

> Any clue on where to start or a code sample that can help on this?

Comment: A) Get some load testing software, or B) write `async` calls for each web service method, and then write a routine that given an integer N, skips to the Nth call, calls the appropriate method using `await`. Between each call, it checks a flag to see if it's time to quit. If not, it continues to the next. When you get to the end, loop back to #1. Call the method many times using `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Use a tool like SOAP UI

Comment: Maybe you can ask this question in the [coyote] tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coyote .Read more about the Coyote framework here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coyote/info

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814993/multiple-concurrent-wcf-calls-from-single-client-to-service